# Adding rel=nofollow to will_paginate links in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate

Is there any way to add "rel=nofollow" to the links created by the will_paginate gem in rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need create your own LinkRenderer and use it

```
require 'will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer'
class PaginationNoFollow < WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::LinkRenderer

  def page_number(page)
    unless page == current_page
      link(page, page, :rel => 'nofollow')
    else
      link(page, page, :rel => 'nofollow', :class => 'on')
    end

  end

end
```

In your view :

```
= will_paginate @users, :renderer => PaginationNoFollow
```

Answer (score 4):

I find that overriding page_number does not work (and also wont take care of your next and back links). Instead, I override rel_value:

```
require 'will_paginate/view_helpers/link_renderer'
class PaginationNoFollow < WillPaginate::ViewHelpers::LinkRenderer
  def rel_value(page)
    case page
    when @collection.previous_page; 'prev nofollow' + (page == 1 ? ' start nofollow' : '')
    when @collection.next_page; 'next nofollow'
    when 1; 'start nofollow'
    else
      'nofollow'
    end
  end
end
```

Add this class to lib, and in your view:

```
will_paginate @users, :renderer => PaginationNoFollow
```

Answer (score 0):

In will_paginate 3 and Rails 3 I had to override ActionView::LinkRenderer like this:

```
require 'will_paginate/view_helpers/action_view'

class PaginationNoFollow < WillPaginate::ActionView::LinkRenderer
  def rel_value(page)
    [super, 'nofollow'].compact.join(' ')
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also place the following meta tag into the `<head>` section of your page:

```
<!-- Prevent webcrawlers to navigate paginations -->
<% if params[:page] %>
  <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<% end %>
```

I found it to be a better approach as you reduce dependency on the will_paginate gem.